# Query string with whitespace IIS7 Redirect using Rewrite module

Tags: redirect, iis-7, url-rewriting

Need to redirect http://www.domain.com/one/two/three/four?addFilter=five&filterValue=six seven

to http://www.domain.com/four/six-seven?showproducts=true

Having problems with the whitespace %20 on URL between six and seven

```
<rule name="PatternRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="one/two/three/four.*" />
          <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="filterValue=([a-z]+).*([a-z]+)" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain.com$" />
          </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain.com/womens/{C:1}-{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Try white space character class:

```
<add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="filterValue=([a-z]+)\s*([a-z]+)" />
```

Comment: I've tried \s* and [\s*] and (%20|\s*) none seem to work, also tried hardcoding the parameters in the query string i.e <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="filterValue=six seven" /> or <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="filterValue=six%20seven" /> but no luck... Any ideas please?